# Iframe rendering error : <rect> attribute width: A negative value is not valid

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I'm trying to integrate an iframe from [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) into a page of my rails app. The app is currently in development and, curiously, sometimes the Ngram Iframe doesn't appear and throws an error :

> ngram-viewer-deps.js:50 Error:  attribute width: A negative
>   value is not valid. ("-152")

Here is the corresponding iframe URL : https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=aspirateur&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caspirateur%3B%2Cc0

Here is the iframe element rendered (I only copy/paste outer HTML here) :

```
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=aspirateur&amp;year_start=1700&amp;year_end=2008&amp;corpus=19&amp;smoothing=3&amp;direct_url=t1%3B%2Caspirateur%3B%2Cc0" width="800" height="335" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Any idea how to prevent this error from happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest i don't now about google Ngram viewer, but i believe the error means that the iframe container width is getting too small. Probably there is a code in that viewer checking the actual width available for the iframe, when the width is extremely small or negative due to overflows from other elements, then it throws this error.

I would start by checking what width is available for the iframe on different screens, especially smaller screens.

A fast try might be a set a min width on the iframe and check if the error still persists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I try various width for the container and the error still happens sometimes. It's weird because sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, with the same parameters...

Comment: @nico_lrx where does it work like in the same screen width?

Comment: Yes, if I refresh the page, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: try to set the min width on the container of the iframe, i think this should work

Comment: I set min-width: 1000px; to the container of the iframe and the errors still appears sometimes